# Class instance in Python Bottle application, is it shared between threads/processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, process, bottle

I have created a class in a Bottle application which handles and stores URL information and is created each time a http request is made:

```
@route('/<fullurl:path>')
    def page_req(fullurl=''):
        urlData = urlReq(request.urlparts[1], fullurl)
```

urlData is the instance name and urlReq is the class name.

Obviously the urlData instance will contain information generated from one request. I'm just wondering what happens if another request comes in before the cycle of the first request has finished and sent its output. Will the second request change the data in urlData or will there be two separate processes each with their own version of urlData?

I've been reading the WSGI processes/threads information and the Bottle docs all afternoon and it's still not immediately clear. I have tried writing a small automated script fire multiple requests at the development server but it seems to hold excess requests off til one has finished. Hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

`bottle.request` is a thread-safe instance of `LocalRequest()`. If accessed from within a request callback, this instance always refers to the **current** request (even on a multithreaded server).

see http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.request

Comment: I read this as the `request` object is thread safe. `urlData` is an instance of my own class rather than a subclass of `request` and gets generated as part of the callback. In the WSGI docs it seems to say that in daemon mode using multiple processes each instance is safe as each process is a subinterpreter. Using multiple threads uses the one interpreter instance and thus each thread has access to the same class instances.... or I could be completely confused and wrong.

Comment: Bottle calls the callback function once for each request, possibly at the same time in different threads. But `urlData` is a local variable in your example. As long as you do not access or change global variables, everything is thread-safe.